# Combine multiple rows with the same timestamp and put values into new columns

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, data-analysis

Assuming I'm having an input df which looks as follows:

| Timestamp | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14:00:00 | A | 25 |
| 14:00:00 | B | 24 |
| 15:00:00 | A | 20 |
| 15:00:00 | C | 21 |
| 16:00:00 | A | 20 |
| 16:00:00 | B | 22 |
| 16:00:00 | C | 23 |
| 16:00:00 | D | 24 |

What I'd like to do now is to merge the rows dependend on the Timestamps but when merging putting the names with the corresponding value into new columns to achieve the following:

| Timestamp | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14:00:00 | 25 | 24 | nan | nan |
| 15:00:00 | 20 | nan | 21 | nan |
| 16:00:00 | 20 | 22 | 23 | 24 |

Are there some build in functions for Pyspark that I could use to achieve this? It would be great if the approach is as generic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need was to `pivot` in pyspark you can use `pivot` to achieve pivoting like below

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[('14:00:00','A',25),
('14:00:00','B',24),
('15:00:00','A',20),
('15:00:00','C',21),
('16:00:00','A',20),
('16:00:00','B',22),
('16:00:00','C',23),
('16:00:00','D',24)],("Timestamp", "name", "value"))


df1 = df.groupBy("Timestamp").pivot("name").sum("value")

df1.show() # this should display the expected results
```